# How can I remove specific selections from the Instance on Points node for a curve?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm making a vine and trying to prevent randomly generated leaves from spawning too close to the start of their parent spline (as well as the branches from spawning too close to the end of the core vine).

[image]

I've stumbled on some things that almost seem to work, but the closest attempts all break the random value node—which is way more important. I suspect the operation needs (or, at least, would be easier) to be done before the Random Value node.

[image]

Thanks in advance for any and all help!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: Thanks to Chris below for a suggesting a Boolean and instead of multiply.

I figured out a solution. Idk if this is the best way, but it works! I researched and tried so many things before asking. Idk how I managed to make this so much harder than it needed to be...

[image]

Comment: just a hint: yes, multiply boolean values works - but for readability reasons a boolean math (and) would be better understandable - i think

Comment: @Chris Ah, that does make more sense. I've updated my answer. Cheers!